# Google Tag Manager enhanced ecommerce events requests

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I need a detailed (hopefully) clarification about the working of Enhanced Ecommerce Events tracking via Google Tag Manager and dataLayer.

Here I'm firing an "event" Analytics Tag, inside GTM, when the trigger below is verified:

[image]

Here, instead, the Tag main properties:

[image]

Those events are correctly fired when I do the appropriate "dataLayer.push" on my ecommerce button clicks. I know that because I get those ecommerce events data into Analytics, but I can't debug image requests directly.

I can check how the dataLayer obj is filled with new properties (below the last scree) but no Tag requests in network console.

Here's the opportunity, for me, to better understand the "first-in" / "first-out" working of dataLayer queue when it's listened by GTM.

[image]

Comment: Did you have any specific question(s)? I'm not clear on what you need help with. Thank you.

Comment: Why I can't see any requests in network console when doing dataLayer.push? How does dataLayer queue works in terms of requesting to Analytics servers / firing relatd Tags ? Thx

Comment: Thx but the tag is already firing based on those events (as I described above) and I'm able to see data in Analytics! The only thing missing here is the requests in console...

Comment: Sorry, can you please clarify what you expect to see in the console? Are you meaning that you would like to see the GA ecommerce transaction hits in the console? You won't see those unless you are actually consoling something. Or do you mean that you want to see the hits in the Network tabs?

Comment: Exactly this, the hit in Network tab. Why there isn't any while I can feed data into Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

Just pushing values to the dataLayer won't necessarily show anything in the network console. You need to use the dataLayer parameters to:

1. fire your tags
2. send data into GA processes (ie. ecommerce)

What you already are pushing is a great start - you have your `event` (which is key) and you have your ecommerce object, presumeably containing the information you need to feed into GA. Now you just need to create the tags that fire based on the event, populated with the your ecommerce details.

Once your tag fires, you should then start to see data in GA.

Edit: To see the hits in the Network tab, you would need to filter by the something like the name of the hit (ie. "collect"). Make sure you are not applying any "type" filters (ie. image, XHR, JS, CSS).

Comment: Thanks nyuen but all your suggestions are already known to me. I need, once for all, a clear "GTM / dataLayer queue and remote requests" working flow explanation. I published Tags based on my dataLayer.pushed events (look at my screenshots above), then I push those events at user click but NO HITS in network console (no filtered at all). On the other hand, I managed to have data in Analytics.

Comment: Can you share your URL and also tell meet where to trigger the same dataLayer pushes?

Comment: Here not, 'cause I can't provide public client info. If you gave me a private contact or mail address, I would send there all the details in order to check. Thanks again.

Comment: You can send to me at cptest@mailinator.com.

Comment: I will do it, thanks so much. I really appreciate it !

Comment: No problem, let me know when you've sent it.

Comment: Did you guys find a resolution to this that can be shared with the world?